# How to embed instagram profile?

Tags: php, iframe, embed, instagram, instagram-api

I have found literally hundreds of ways to embed instagram gallery in a website, but what I need is to embed the whole profile, t.i. if you look at this profile for example: https://www.instagram.com/exampleprofile/ there's a profile image, about, title and a follow button.

How can I embed the profile with this header information as well not only the images in its gallery? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is to use the API.
You can get user information with this endpoint:

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users

Comment: FYI: This one is actually a Legacy API

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no straightforward way to do that, you need to:

1. Create an Instagram Client application
2. Get your client details
3. Authenticate

**1. Create an Instagram Client application**

You have to create your own instagram application [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/register/):

**2. Get your client details**

In your Instagram Developer account, click "Manage Clients" and take note of the "Client ID", "Client Secret" and "Redirect URI" because you'll need them soon. Make sure you are using a complete URL for your Redirect URI, such as "https://drupal.org".

**3. Authenticate**

3.a Using CURL
First, add this into your browser:

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=YOUR-CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=YOUR REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code&scope=public_content
Note that the REDIRECT-URI above should be URL encoded, such as https%3A%2F%2Fdrupal.org.

You'll then be redirected to the url you redirected to. Take note of the url as this is where you receive the code you need:

```
http://your-redirect-uri?code=YOU-NEED-THIS-CODE
```

Now open up your terminal and paste in this (adding your specific id, secret, redirect uri, & code):

```
curl -F 'client_id=YOUR CLIENT_ID HERE' \
-F 'client_secret=YOUR CLIENT_SECRET HERE' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=YOUR AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI HERE' \
-F 'code=THE CODE YOU RECEIVED' \
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

You should receive something that looks like this:

```
{
"access_token": "fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d",
"user": {
    "id": "1574083",
    "username": "snoopdogg",
    "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "profile_picture": "..."
}
}
```

**3.b Using browser**
Build the following url and paste it on your browser:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[your client id]&redirect_uri=[your redirect uri]&response_type=token
```

You may see the following error "Implicit authentication is disabled". If so, then you have to edit your Instagram Client, go to the Security tab, and disable the option **Disable implicit OAuth**, you can enable this back once you get to the following point.

If everything went well you should have been redirected to an URI that looks like this

```
https://my_redirect.uri/#access_token=xxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyy.zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

On the access_token key, the "x" part (all before the first period) is your User Id.

**4. Create request for Instagram API and then parse the response object**

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxxxxxxxxx/media/recent/?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyy.zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

Instagram API: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users

***The source:*** https://www.drupal.org/node/2746185

Comment: Unfortunately, the Instagram API has been deprecated as of December 2018; this will no longer work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the new Facebook Graph API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media

You'll need a developer account with an Application and Instagram "Basic Display" permissions. From there, much of [Omar Alahmed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43640061/1522007) is still applicable, including authorization via OAuth at https://api.instagram.com (this part of the API was not deprecated).